# Transfer Function of PI Controller

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, pid-controller, transfer-function, error-amplifier

Circuit below is an op-amp summer combined with PI controller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2e43A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- What is transfer function of this circut?
- How to calculate each R and C value if I want to build PI with parameter gain = 8, time constant  = 1/15?

Notes:
V_ref = Reference voltage
V_act = Actual voltage
V_err = Amplified error voltage

Comment: Question: What is the emaning of your requirement "gain=8" ? The transfer function of your circuit always approaches 0 dB for rising frequencies. And what means "1/15"?

Comment: This won't provide any DC gain. Is this what you want? only a time varying proportional contribution?

Answer (score 1):

For a start you might as well get rid of R2 and R3 - all they do is reduce the setpoint at which the error is calculated and do not at all affect the AC transfer function of the Op-amp. If you reduce this further to imagining Vref at 0V, the AC transfer function again is unaltered.

This leaves you with a simple inverting op-amp configuration to solve: -

\$\dfrac{V_{ERR}}{V_{(+IN)}} = 1 + \dfrac{X_{feedback}}{R_1}\$

So, calculate what Xf is in terms of jw or s, then do some math and you have your transfer function. If you want to then accomadate R2 and R3 then it's a simple case of multiplying the answer by: -

\$\dfrac{R3}{R2+R3}\$

The actual DC value of Vref is unimportant unless this is also being moved around rapidly.

If you want a gain of 8 concentrate on R4 and R1 as the important components. Clearly at DC the circuit is an integratorbut at some point the AC gain should be largely defined by those two resistors with C1 being much less significant. If C1 isn't insignificant for mid-band AC gain then you have to assume that C1 is much smaller than C2 and therefore can be realized as being in parallel with R4.

From my experience I would usually say that C2 as the main integration capacitor and C1 is a high frequency roll-off component that barely affects mid-band gain.

Comment: What is V(+IN)? Both input V_ref and V_act are DC. V_act has ripple about 7% (50 Hertz).

Comment: Andy-do you really expect that R2 and R3 will INCREASE the gain? Isn`t it a simple voltage division with a factor<1 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure PI controller approaching a gain A=8 you have to set **C1=0** and **R4/R1=8**. Then, the time constant of the integrating part is determined by the product **Ti=R1C2**. Now - if for a specific reason you want a gain below the value of "8" for very large frequencies (beyond the zero created by the product R4C2) you can add a small capacitor C1. Thus, the corresponding time constant R4C1 should be much smaller than R4C2. Hence, **C1 < C2**